# Symfony2: Token was not found in the SecurityContext

Tags: authentication, symfony

A firewall that should allow anonymous connection to a URL is instead requiring authentication.  For example, `/reports/foodbank/2013/10` should simply provide a set of values rather than require login.  Syntax error?

#### security.yml includes:

```
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    foodbank:
      pattern: ^/reports/foodbank/~
      anonymous: ~

    login_firewall:
        pattern:    ^/login$
        anonymous:  ~

    secured_area:
        pattern:    ^/
        form_login:
          default_target_path: /home
          use_referer: true

        logout:
          target: /login

access_control:
    - { path: ^/reports/foodbank/~, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A return visit to the documentation revealed paths are regex expressions, something with which I am (unfortunately) only vaguely familiar.  But the following modifications made it work:

foodbank:
  pattern: ^/reports/foodbank/*
  anonymous: ~

and

access_control:
    - { path: ^/reports/foodbank/*, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }